# How to debug a tab in Google Chrome that freezes right from the browser start?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

In a vue web application, I have the issue that I have some deep links (example.com/app/some/123) that are handled by the application (vue-router).

*Sometimes* (not always), for whatever reason when clicking such a link (in Outlook or from a desktop shortcut) when no browser window is opened, Chrome starts but immediately freezes (tab becomes unresponsive).

It feels like there is some redirect loop going on in my application code that causes this freeze. But my issue is that I have no clue on how to debug this to find the spot:

- Opening the devtools is possible using the menu but JS files/code does not "load" - Scripts tab stays empty
- Clicking the pause button does nothing, the same applies to pressing F8 (pause script execution)
- The profiler cannot start (stays at "initializing").

I also have the feeling that this happens when a new version of the app (js bundle) is published but Chrome has some previous version cached. It feels this more often produces the issue. But this is just a guess.

Clicking the pause button/F8 is my regular procedure to tackle such things to find the spot where we are in the JS code at the moment. But unfortunately, here, this does not work as most of the browser is unresponsive.

The only way to close Chrome is to kill it via the task manager.

Is there any way to enable additional logging via Chrome settings or activate an "immediate debug session" right when the browser process starts to somehow get closer to the JS code that freezes the whole tab?
So ideally that somehow, right from the browser start, a profile of the "debug session" is saved even if the browser is process-killed that can later be inspected?

Answer (score 0):

You could try webQsee (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webqsee-web-sniffer-recor/gamdpfnfkjknkimfbboonmgdfnondfme). The extension provides some usefull export features that might help you identifying the root cause.

**Event Snapshot**
Exports Screenshot, Cookies, Network and Console output. A lot of info but it is a proprietary format, in can only be analysed in the extension itself.

**Excel Export**
Like an HAR export, but also including Console output.

These two export options (and more) are available via the export menu located at the bottom of the extension window.

[image: webQsee Export Options]

Comment: thanks for the idea. As this is obviously your tool, does it still work if the Chrome tab freezes?

Comment: Hi,
yes it is our tool. If it works will depend on what exactly happens when you observe the "freeze behavior".